# Settings won't open on Ubuntu 21.10

Tags: gnome, settings, wacom, 21.10

I'm not 100% sure what's going on here. When trying to open settings in the terminal, I got this

```
(gnome-control-center:6799): libwacom-CRITICAL **: 21:55:59.349: Duplicate match of 'usb:256c:006e:Tablet Monitor Pen' on device 'GAOMON S56K'.

(gnome-control-center:6799): GLib-CRITICAL **: 21:55:59.350: g_once_init_leave: assertion 'result != 0' failed
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I removed libwacom, and ran this code

`dconf reset -f /org/gnome/control-center/`

I was then able to open settings! I proceeded to go through and set everything up, then I got to the Wacom settings for my Intuos S, and settings closed and the same GLib error as before appeared in the terminal.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

EDIT #1

This is an upgraded version from Bionic Beaver, going through the Software updater, so it went 18.04 LTS > 20.04 LTS > 21.04 > 21.10

Comment: @user535733 I believe op edited with the info.

Comment: There is no tested, supported path from 20.04 to 21.04, so your system is suspect. Try a 21.10 LiveUSB's 'Try Ubuntu" environment. If you can duplicate the issue in the 21.10 "Try Ubuntu" environment, then file a bug report. If you cannot duplicate the issue in the 21.10 "Try Ubuntu" environment, then the problem is something unusual or nonstandard in your system, and a reinstall is the simplest and fastest option to resolve.

Comment: @user535733 Is it possible to do a reinstall without loosing data? I was also having this problem on Bionic Beaver, i went ahead and updated to 21.10 thinking it may fix whatever I screwed up-

Comment: It's *possible*, if you make the right choices when running the installer. But you might also make the wrong choice and wipe out all your data. People do that. If your data is valuable to you, it should be backed up anyway.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was to unplug the tablet from my computer, then Settings started without an issue.
The only problem is, upon plugging the tablet back in, Settings promptly crashes. I guess the temporary solution is to simply unplug your tablet when messing with settings.